# Ajax call not working when navigating back to previous page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, caching

I have a page in php where i m loading some div s on scrolling to bottom with ajax call
But when i click on any div to go to next page and when i come back from navigated page,my ajax scrolling which is loading content on to bottom of windows does not work.
Below is my code

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'table1');

   if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
      }
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Load data after page scroll </title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function(){
    scrollMore();
});

function scrollMore(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())){

    var offset = $('[id^="myData_"]').length; // here we find out total records on page.
    var records = $(".allData").text();

    $(window).unbind("scroll");
        if(records != offset){
            $("#loaderImg").html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $("#loaderImg").show();
            loadMoreData(offset);
        }
    }
}

function loadMoreData(offset){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        async:false,
        url: 'getMoreData.php',
        data: 'offset='+offset,
        success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
            $("#loaderImg").empty();
            $("#loaderImg").hide();
            $(".loadData :last").after(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("ajax error occured…"+data);
        }
    }).done(function(){
        $(window).bind("scroll",function(){
        scrollMore();   
    });
    });
}


});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $sql ="select * from xml";
    $countsql3 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die("Cannot Get Pname Info: (".mysql_error().")");
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($countsql3);

    $limit = 20;
    $offset = 0;
    $mysql = "select * from xml limit ".$offset.", ".$limit."";
    $countsql3 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $mysql) or die("Cannot Get Pname Info: (".mysql_error().")");


?>

<div class="totalData">Total Records Found:<span class="allData"><?php echo $numrows;?></span></div>

<div class="mainDiv">
<div class="tableRow">
<div class="firstColumn"><strong>#</strong></div>
<div class="secondColumn"><strong>Record</strong></div>
</div>
<?php
$i = 1;
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($countsql3)){ ?>
<div class="tableRow loadData" id="myData_<?php echo $i;?>">
<div class="firstColumn"><a href="nextpage.php"><?php echo $result['PID']; ?></a></div>
<div class="secondColumn"><?php echo $result['PID']?></div>
</div>
<?php $i++; }?>
<div class="tableRow">
<div class="secondColumn" id="loaderImg" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

getMoreData.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'table1');

   if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
      }

$offset = (isset($_REQUEST['offset']) && $_REQUEST['offset']!='') ? $_REQUEST['offset'] : '';
$limit = 10;
$qry1 ="select * from xml limit ".$offset.", ".$limit."";
$countsql3 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $qry1) or die("Cannot Get Pname Info: (".mysql_error().")");
$i = ++$offset;
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($countsql3)){ ?>
<div class="tableRow loadData" id="myData_<?php echo $i;?>">
<div class="firstColumn"><a href="nextpage.php"><?php echo $result['PID']; ?></a></div>
<div class="secondColumn"><?php echo $result['PID']?></div>
</div>
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

nextpage.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
hi 
</body>
</html>
```

Please look at code and guide me for solution

Answer (score 0):

On your Ajax call set cache to false, it may be that the browser is caching the call because it is the same and not actually hiring it off. Disabling the ajax cache will force it to send a new request each time.

```
function loadMoreData(offset){
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    async:false,
    url: 'getMoreData.php',
    cache: false,
    data: 'offset='+offset,
    success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
        $("#loaderImg").empty();
        $("#loaderImg").hide();
        $(".loadData :last").after(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert("ajax error occured…"+data);
    }
}).done(function(){
    $(window).bind("scroll",function(){
    scrollMore();   
});
});
```

Another way of doing this is by adding in a variable within the ajax function that forces the method to get the current date, so:

```
function loadMoreData(offset){

var dateNow = new Date().getTime() + Math.random();

$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    async:false,
    url: 'getMoreData.php',
    cache: false,
    data: {offset: offset, time: dateNow }, 
    success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
        $("#loaderImg").empty();
        $("#loaderImg").hide();
        $(".loadData :last").after(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert("ajax error occured…"+data);
    }
}).done(function(){
    $(window).bind("scroll",function(){
    scrollMore();   
});
});
```

Comment: didnt work fully sir,sometimes it works,and sometimes doesnot.what can be done on this @Armlock29

Comment: See edit for another fix regarding caching, basically you force it to get the current time and send that through as the data will always actively change.

Comment: Ok last thing i can fix off is to to add: var dateNow = new Date().getTime() + Math.random();